# Yii Front Controller Implementation before Routing

Tags: yii, front-controller

I want to implement a language Setter for all Controllers and need to run this method before the Routing to the Controller -> the front Controller.

If have implemented a method in my Controller Class, but for some usages it must be run earlier before controller initilisation

```
class Controller extends CController
{
  public function __construct($id, $module = null)
  {


    // Set the application language 

    if (isset($_GET['language']))
    {
        $lang = $_GET['language'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`onBeginRequest`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onBeginRequest-detail) event of the application. This usually requires you to add some code to your `index.php`. Here's a quick example:

```
$app = Yii::createWebApplication($config);
$app->onBeginRequest = function($event) {
    // ... whatever you want to do
}
$app->run();
```

Of course instead of a closure function you can also attach any other valid [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Answer (score -1):

You can override beforeAction($action)

```
class Controller extends CController
{
  public function beforeAction($action)
  {
    $language = !empty($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en';
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
  }
}
```

Comment: the beforeAction is executed after the __construct function not before